# Dynamically created class as DataContract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

Is there any way to return an array of objects of type `DynamicClass` from WCF method?

I'm using [Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) in my WCF service, so as to `select` columns of database table , as per the request from clients. The client code should look like this:

```
//client side code
string whereClause = "FeatureId >= 6 and FeatureId <= 180";
string selectClause = "New(FeatureName as Name, FeatureId as Id)";
client.RequestAsync("Feature", "FeatureDB", whereClause, selectClause);
```

*Feature* is the name of the table from which I want to `select` two columns only, viz. *FeatureName* and *FeatureId*, satisfying the condition in the `where` clause.

Here, the problem is that the query runs fine on the server, but WCF is unable to send it back to the client. My guess is that the dynamically created class which defines only the selected columns is not declared `DataContract`, so WCF isn't able to work with it.

So any solution to this problem?

Or any alternative? The goal is, I don't want to return all columns of the database table, because I don't need all of them on the client side. So I don't see any point sending all columns back to the client, who will discard it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to work around this by using Reflection to decorate your fields with the appropriate attributes, however this may still present an issue for any client process that consumes your WCF service, as the generated section of your service contract will be non-deterministic, i.e. xs:any in the schema.

Better to try and strongly type your WCF contracts wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing a [WCF Data Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106)?

Comment: What does it do? Does it do what I want to do? An answer should try answering my question. Or else it was more suited for comment.

Comment: "...enables exposing any data source as a web-friendly data feed..." I suggest you see this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/FT12

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.